# Evaluate $\int \frac {\sin x}{7+\cos x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate $\int \frac {\sin x}{7+\cos x^2}dx$

Is there an analytical solution to this?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear if you mean $\cos(x^2)$ or  $(\cos x)^2$.  If it's the former, then I don't think you'll have any luck finding an analytical solution.  If it's the latter, then you would proceed as mathlove did in his answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that your $\cos x^2$ means $(\cos x)^2=\cos^2x.$

HINT :

Letting $\cos x=u$, you'll get
$$\int\frac{-1}{7+u^2}du=\int\frac{-1/7}{1+(u/\sqrt 7)^2}du.$$

In general, if you have
$$\int\sin x\cdot f(\cos x)dx,$$
letting $u=\cos x$ would help.

On the other hand, if you have
$$\int\cos x\cdot f(\sin x)dx,$$
letting $u=\sin x$ would help.